# Help rusting off integration

Tags: calculus, integration

It's been one year since I worked with integrals so it's a bit hard for me to get the grasp of it again, here is an example of integral that I can't slove at the moment.

I am thinking that maybe I should break the fraction and then go with replacement technique but I can't solve it.

Here is the problem: 
$$
\int \frac{-2x+4}{(x^2+1)(x-1)^2} dx
$$

Comment: Use Parial fractions

Comment: Just do what Surb answered. This is the typical problem of partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Find $A,B,C,D$ s.t.
$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x-1)^2}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{C}{x-1}+\frac{D}{(x-1)^2}.$$

Comment: I am not used to partial fraction decomposition, but i am trying to understand what you wrote. thanks

Comment: Notice that it's a very important tool. See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: I got some help from this example:http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm

Comment: but i am reaching a really big and kinda complex situation when i try to find a,b,c,d